# WinDbg Unresponsive After Crash

Tags: windows, debugging, driver, windbg

I am debugging a driver in a VirtualBox VM, with WinDbg attached to the target via COM port exposed to the host as a named pipe.

Debugging works fine - I can pause the target, set breakpoints, step through source files .etc

When my driver encounters a fatal error WinDbg dumps the following output to the console:

```
*** Fatal System Error: 0x00000050
                       (0xFFFFF88004126840,0x0000000000000001,0xFFFFF88003E12690,0x0000000000000000)

Driver at fault: 
***  MYDRIVER.sys - Address FFFFF88003E12690 base at FFFFF88003E12000, DateStamp 51249ae5
.
Break instruction exception - code 80000003 (first chance)

A fatal system error has occurred.
Debugger entered on first try; Bugcheck callbacks have not been invoked.

A fatal system error has occurred.

Connected to Windows 7 7601 x64 target at (Wed Feb 20 09:57:54.670 2013 (UTC + 0:00)), ptr64 TRUE
Loading Kernel Symbols
...............................................................
................................................................
..............
Loading User Symbols
.....
Loading unloaded module list
.....Unable to enumerate user-mode unloaded modules, Win32 error 0n30
Loading Wow64 Symbols
..........................................................
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

Use !analyze -v to get detailed debugging information.

BugCheck 50, {fffff88004126840, 1, fffff88003e12690, 0}
```

The little status box on the debugger command line is blank, and the debugger does not respond to the commands I type in.

I want to see the call stack and inspect the machine state, but the debugger remains unresponsive. Pressing BREAK/CONTINUE seems to have no effect.

I don't understand - what is the state of the debugger at this point?

I have a suspicion that my whole debugging setup is just very, very slow.

Comment: You crashed the operating system, pretty normal when a driver crashes.  Of course the debugger won't work anymore either, that COM port is a dead parrot.  You can get a post-mortem analysis from the core dump.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff538042%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: I'm not convinced that you are correct. After about five minutes the debugger does wake up.

Comment: Debugger can be pretty slow, especially via com ports. Also put the relevant symbols files at fast, accessible location (e.g., not on remote network) and don't load the OS symbols (they are huge and usually loaded from remote host)

Comment: @icepack thanks for the advice. Do you have any references or tutorials about this? I guess I am probably loading the OS symbols using the Microsoft Symbol Server.

Comment: Just remove all the references that you don't recognize from the File->Symbol files path. Leave only path to symbols of your own driver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debugging via com port is very slow, you must switch to virtualkd - http://virtualkd.sysprogs.org/ (its use shared memory between host and guest and much much faster). And don`t press anything while you waiting, its slow down process a little bit more. 
In general com is outdated and while debugging, without vm, all use firewire or usb interfaces.